# Symbols at node in latex and their explanation

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Let’s say, I draw a diagram like this

```
% \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale = 0.8, line cap = round, line join = round,>=triangle 45, x = 1.0cm, y = 1.0cm]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0) node[left] {O};
\draw [->](O)-- (3, 0.5) node[right] {A} node[midway, below] {$\vec{P}$};
\draw [->](3, 0.5)-- (4, 3) node[above] {B} node[midway, right] {$\vec{Q}$};
\draw [->](O)-- (4, 3) node[midway, above] {$\vec{R}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My questions:

1. My writing of O, A, B is correct or should I use `$O$`,`$A$` and `$B$`?

   Now, I want to explain my figure. So, I write like:
   To add vectors `$\vec{P}$` and `$\vec{Q}$`, the origin of `$\vec{Q}$` i.e., A is kept at the terminal point of `$\vec{P}$` and the shortest distance between O and B gives `$\vec{P} + \vec{Q}$` i.e.,

   ```
   \begin{equation*}
   \vec{R} = \vec{P} + \vec{Q}
   \end{equation*}
   ```
2. or here again should I use `$O$`, `$A$` and `$B$`?
3. If I want to represent in the diagram, the length OA by l, then should I use l or `$l$`?

What is the best practice for (1) and (2) and (3).

Comment: This looks like a notation question to me but not a TeX question.

Comment: Since all of them are symbols in formulae, I would go for the `$$`